# JS Replacing whole word with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Alright so I am trying to check if string contains @, if so it should delete the entire word that is part of that @

For example, lets say that string says '@someone' it should replace entire '@someone' with for example 'Hello'.

My current code just replaces the @ sign and not the entire word

```
$(document).on('click', '.mention_each_data', function() {
    var format = "@" + $(this).find('p').text();
    element_moderated.val(element_moderated.val().replace(/(\s*)@\b/g, format));
});
```

Comment: So, match the word with `\w+`, use `/\s*@\w+/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'@bean'.replace(/@\w/g,'t')
"tean"

'@bean'.replace(/@\w+/g,'t')
"t"
```

You have to add the + which matches @ and at least one word and will replace the whole match.